# Why I can not search the first word or last word in a Solr field?

Tags: xml, solr, lucene

I am a Solr beginner and I just used it for my project for 1 month, from the first time, everything were fine but I got a problem. It was if I have a sentence like this "when you love someone, the world is shining". If I used 'when you' or 'is shining' there is no result but when I tried to use 'you love' or 'world is', or just 'love' or kind of, the results are appeared. I want to ask how to configure by schemal.xml file, or did I make something wrong, thank you!

Here is the schema.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema name="minimal" version="1.1">
  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false" />
  <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" />

  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>

  <field name="dplname" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="mail" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
  <field name="phone" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
  <field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

  <copyField source="dplname" dest="text"/>
  <copyField source="mail" dest="text"/>
  <copyField source="phone" dest="text"/>

  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" docValues="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" docValues="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" docValues="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" docValues="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
  <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>

  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
</schema>
```

**Update**: I used this query to search: dplname:*is shining* or kind of.

Comment: how are you searching ? as in what is your query?

Comment: Hi, my query is dplname:*is shining* or kind of.

Comment: are you doing wild card searches on purpose ? what happens if you only search like this `dplname:shining`

Comment: It works but I want to ask if I search by *is shining* or 'is shining', there is no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. so you need to understand how text is analyzed and tokenized in solr.
In your case if you look in your schema.xml

```
<analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
```

What this means is that while indexing the documents `StandardTokenizerFactory` will be applied which breaks the sentence based on whitespace and some other delimiters.

read here for details https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-StandardTokenizer)

e.g your sentence :

> when you love someone, the world is shining

will be broken into following tokens

> when, you, love,someone,the, world,is,shining

so total 8 tokens.Note `,` will also be removed since this is also a delimiter.

then `StopFilterFactory` filter is applies which will remove the stop words which are present in your stopwords.txt file. 
(stop words are common words which you do not want to index as they kind of do not make sense in searching.

Read here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-StopFilter)

lets assume the stop words are

> you,the,is

so after the second filter you are left with these tokens(since stopwords are removed)

> when,love,someone,world,shining

Now the third filter is lowercase filter , which will convert all the tokens to lower case.

So to summarize when all said and done your sentence

> when you love someone, the world is shining

is indexed into followoing tokens

> when,love,someone,world,shining

**Lets talk about searching aka query**

in your schema.xml you have following

```
<analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
```

what this means that the above analyzers will be performed for every query.

So when you search for `dplname:shining`
the StandardTokenizerFactory will analyze it since there is no delimiter nothing will happen to `shining`, since it is also not a stopword either it wont be removed by  `StopFilterFactory` and the `LowerCaseFilterFactory` only changes it to lower case.(if its already not)

so the final token which solr will search for is `shining`, which it finds in the index and hence you get back the results.

Lets look at the other query

> dplname:is shining

Note: The field is only valid for the term that it directly precedes, so in the above query `is` is searched in `dplname` field but since there is nothing in front of `shining` it will be searched in the default field (in this case the text field).

so essentially the query becomes(since the defaultOperator is AND it will be added in the query)

> dplname:is AND text:shining

so solr is searching for a doc which has `is` in the `dplname` field and `shining` in the text field. which it cant find.

Read here for the query parsing: http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html